# Choosing Fax Attachment during DocuSign Embedded Signing results in "cancel" event

Tags: tags, docusignapi, fax

I am making API calls to create an embedded signing URL token that enables our end user to see a DocuSign document.  One of the tabs on the document is a file attachment.  The file attachment appears when the user clicks on the tab, giving the option to "Choose File" or "Send By Fax".

If the user clicks on "Send By Fax", he/she gets a message saying that a cover sheet will be printed at the end of the signing process.  The user can click on "OK".

After all of the tabs are validated a "FINISH" button appears.  The user clicks on "FINISH" and then a "Send Attachment By Fax" message appears.  The user clicks on "Print Cover Page" which downloads the cover page PDF.  The user prints the PDF.

Then the user clicks on DONE, to close the dialog.  Control is returned to the ReturnURL along with the parameter "event=cancel".

According to the documentation (https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Post%20Recipient%20View.htm?Highlight=fax_pending), the event parameter should be "event=fax_pending".

Is there any way to get the correct event parameter ("event=fax_pending" rather than "event=cancel") when awaiting a fax?  Without the correct parameter, when we parse the response parameters we are lead to believe that the user canceled when in fact he/she is just planning to fax the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to repro this and was not able to repro.  It is possible that you are on the older signing experience and experiencing a bug.

My experience:
1) Send envelope from a template
2) Create recipient view with respective information
3) access recipient view
4) Click Continue
5) Click "Other Actions" dropdown
6) Select "Print & Sign"
7) Click "Fax"
8) Click Download to download the PDF
9) Click "Finish"
10) Get result: default URL &?event=fax_pending appended

My result was:
https://www....com/?event=fax_pending

Comment: We have suppressed the Print & Sign option within "Other Actions" so we are not following that path.  It appears that I didn't make it 100% clear that I was referring to faxing the attachment only, not the document.  So the signer fills out the document; after all of the tabs are validated a "Finish" button appears, and then the remaining steps occur as described in my third paragraph above.  So you reproduce this by choosing to fax the attachment, not the document.

Comment: If you have a chance, can you try this clarified path?  If you need any further information let me know.  This result is reliably reproduced.

Comment: Thanks, have you followed-up with support to log a bug for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I did post a support request to support@docusign.com, and after a few days got a definitive answer.  This event result is a known bug.  However support told me of a work-around that is satisfactory for our purposes, which is to suppress the fax option during the attachment process.  Here are the steps I followed:

- log in to demo.docusign.net (na2.docusign.net for production)
- click on preferences (drop-down in upper right)
- click on branding (at left)
- click on edit (to edit the brand)
- click on resources
- under signing resource click on Download Master
- That downloads an XML file.
- Add the following element as the last sub-element of : false
- Save the file.
- Click on Upload Captive Resource and upload the changed file